# Windows Server AppFabricCache, Exception, Check the client version

Tags: c#, powershell, caching, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I'm trying to build and run [WindowsServerAppFabricSamples](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19603) CacheAPISample application. I had to install Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching version 2.3.1.0 from nuget to build. My config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataCacheClients" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
    <section name="cacheDiagnostics" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon.DiagnosticsConfigurationSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
  </configSections>
  <dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default" />
  </dataCacheClients>          
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

When I run the application I get exception with message:

> Check the client version. It should be within the allowed version
>   range on the server. If necessary, upgrade the client to the allowed
>   version.

Exception trace:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException was unhandled
  HelpLink=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164049
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=ErrorCode<ERRCA0019>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Check the client version. It should be within the allowed version range on the server. If necessary, upgrade the client to the allowed version.
  Source=Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client
  ErrorCode=19
  SubStatus=-1
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ErrStatus errStatus, Guid trackingId, Exception responseException, Byte[][] payload, EndpointID destination)
       at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ResponseBody respBody, EndpointID destination)
       at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.EstablishConnection(IEnumerable`1 servers, RequestBody request, Func`3 sendMessageDelegate, DataCacheReadyRetryPolicy retryPolicy)
       at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.WcfClientProtocol.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 servers)
       at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName, CreateNewCacheDelegate cacheCreationDelegate, DataCacheInitializationViaCopyDelegate initializeDelegate)
       at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName)
       at CacheAPISample.Program.PrepareClient() in c:\Programming\WindowsServerAppFabricSamples\Samples\CS\Cache\CacheAPISample\CacheAPISample\Program.cs:line 617
       at CacheAPISample.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Programming\WindowsServerAppFabricSamples\Samples\CS\Cache\CacheAPISample\CacheAPISample\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Responsible code part is:

```
private void PrepareClient()
{
    List<DataCacheServerEndpoint> servers = new List<DataCacheServerEndpoint>(1);
    servers.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint("localhost", 22233));
    DataCacheFactoryConfiguration configuration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
    configuration.Servers = servers;
    configuration.LocalCacheProperties = new DataCacheLocalCacheProperties();
    DataCacheClientLogManager.ChangeLogLevel(System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Off);
    myCacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(configuration);
    // Breaks after this comment.
    myDefaultCache = myCacheFactory.GetCache("default");
}
```

In administration Windows PowerShell I have run `get-cachehost` command. Here's what I got:

```
HostName : CachePort Service Name            Service Status Version Info
-------------------- ------------            -------------- ------------
KOKICA:22233         AppFabricCachingService UP             3 [3,3][1,3]
```

Both server and client application are running on the same Windows 8.1 machine. AppFabric 1.1 is installed. Cache dependencies

Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll, 
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core

are in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\v2.2\ref\Caching

File version is 1.0.5137.0. Any attempts to help me resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries you referred are for Azure Cache, whereas what you are looking for is client libraries for onPremise Appfabric for windows server.

If you have installed Microsoft Appfabric 1.1 for windows server from here:http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27115,
You need to right click your client project properties and refer client dlls(Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll and Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.dll.) from c:\Program Files\Windows Server Appfabric or whichever folder you installed it to. (While installing, you should have checked the check box 'install client'

Refer this link for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334398(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: Thx. Can not confirm the answer is correct yet. Have changed references. Have set `new DataCacheSecurity(DataCacheSecurityMode.None, DataCacheProtectionLevel.None);` on the client. Have adjusted   `set-cacheclustersecurity None None` on the server. Windows firewall is down for private netwoks. I'm getting exception: `ErrorCode<ERRCA0019>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Check the client version. It should be within the allowed version range on the server. If necessary, upgrade the client to the allowed version.`

Comment: can you check whether none of the old references are GAC'd?(Go to <windows-drive>\Windows\assembly and delete all references starting with Microsoft.ApplicationServer.caching.). Rebuild the project with new references and try again.
IF this is not working,can u paste the result of Get-CacheHost from powershell? For seeing the full result, you might need to increase the width of powershell window.

Comment: Result of `Get-CacheHost`: HostName    : KOKICA
PortNo      : 22233
ServiceName : AppFabricCachingService
Status      : Up
VersionInfo : 3[3,3][1,3]

Comment: I've checked loaded assemblies. I've put breakpoint before line that throws exception and entered AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() in Quick Watch window. {Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35}
{Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35} Does it seem ok?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Windows Server AppFabric Cookbook, chapter [Installing Cache Client Assemblies](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/microsoft-wcf/9781849684187/1dot-installing-windows-server-appfabric/id286697955#X2ludGVybmFsX0h0bWxWaWV3P3htbGlkPTk3ODE4NDk2ODQxODclMkZpZDI4Njc1MTI4NiZxdWVyeT0=), paragraph How it works... reminded me again, just as @Alfan tiried, to check, for the nth time, server service executable file version and client assemblies file version on the disk.

The confusion is that I have installed *AppFabric Cache* from [MS download center page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27115) (`...\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server`), but already had *Windows Azure SDK v2.2* installed (`...\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.2\ref\Caching`). Both installs have Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.dll files.

I have referenced SDK's files (v 1.0.5137.0) and versions did not match. I referenced assemblies from AppFabric Cache (v 1.0.4632.0) folder which has resolved my problem.

Side note
Both file versions report same version number when running `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`
from client application.